# OneSignal & Firebase Cloud Function - Returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, onesignal

I'm trying to use cloud function to trigger a push notification whenever a new chat message document is created in Firestore.

I'm also using OneSignal as shown in the code below. However, cloud function keeps complaining my function doesn't return a promise or value and I'm not sure what function to return here. Where and what should I return?

```
exports.newChatNotification = functions.firestore.
document('channels/{userId}/thread/{docId}').
onCreate((snap, context) => {

  // Get the values of the newly created document
  const newValue = snap.data();

  // Access the "content" field
  const content = newValue.content;
  console.log(content);

  // Access the "userID" field
  const userID = newValue.userID;
  console.log(userID);

  const docId = context.params.docId;
  console.log(docId);

  // OneSignal notification sending
  var sendNotification = function(data) {
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization": "{Authorization token}"
    };

    var options = {
      host: "onesignal.com",
      port: 443,
      path: "/api/v1/notifications",
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers
    };

    var https = require('https');
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
      res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Response:");
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR:");
      console.log(e);
    });

    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    req.end();
  };

  var message = { 
    app_id: "APP_ID",
    contents: {"en": content},
    include_player_ids: ["PLAYER_ID_1", "PLAYER_ID_2"]
  };

  sendNotification(message);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions requires you to return a promise that resolves when all the asynchronous work is complete in your function.  That's how you tell Cloud Functions that it's safe to clean up and terminate the function.  This is not optional - if you don't return a promise correctly like this, the work might never complete, and your code will simply not work.

I suggest [reading the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) about this, and be sure to understand how JavaScript promises work.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I read the doc and understand how Promises work. However, I tried adding "return" to the sendNotification function but the same error popped up. So instead of `sendNotification(message);`, I changed to `return sendNotification(message);`. Where should I correctly place the `return` at?